# exporting xml value from CLOB data field in oracle using multiple namespace

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a table which contains x number of records. One of the fields is a CLOB and contains XML with a particular field
Here is a very shortened version of the XML

```
 <metadata xml:lang="en"
 xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:srv="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv" xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <gmd:GEMINI_Metadata>
        <gmd:fileIdentifier>
            <gco:CharacterString>cf40a39a-0721-4fd4-84f3-adc28aee1158</gco:CharacterString>
        </gmd:fileIdentifier>
    <gmd:dateStamp>
        <gco:Date>2019-01-16</gco:Date>
    </gmd:dateStamp>
  </gmd:GEMINI_Metadata>
</metadata>
```

What I would like to do is get characterstring value from the fileIdentifier tag using SQL
I have tried the following

```
select EXTRACT (XMLType (DOCUMENTATION), '//fileIdentifier//gco:CharacterString','xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"', 'xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"') as DOCUMENTATION from sde.gdb_items_vw where name = 'testTable'
```

i get the following

```
ORA-00939: too many arguments for function
```

If I try only specifying one tag and one namespace like this

```
select EXTRACT (XMLType (DOCUMENTATION), '//gmd:fileIdentifier','xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"') as DOCUMENTATION from sde.gdb_items_vw where name = 'testTable';
```

I get the following

```
DOCUMENTATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<gmd:fileIdentifier xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"><gco:CharacterS
```

So what is the correct way of getting a particular tag that has multiple namespaces within its tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method is to use XMLTABLE. Here you can easily specify the namespaces.

```
SELECT doc AS documentation
  FROM sde.gdb_items_vw,
       XMLTABLE( xmlnamespaces( 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd' AS "gmd",
                                'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS "xsi",
                                'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco' AS "gco",
                                'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv' AS "srv",
                                'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts' AS "gts",
                                'http://www.opengis.net/gml' AS "gml",
                                'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' AS "xlink",
                                'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt' AS "msxsl"                                
       ), 
       '/metadata' PASSING XMLTYPE(documentation)
       COLUMNS doc VARCHAR2(1000) PATH 'gmd:fileIdentifier/gco:CharacterString'
       );
```

Result:

```
DOCUMENTATION                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
------------------------------------
cf40a39a-0721-4fd4-84f3-adc28aee1158
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesnt seem to be picking up the value "cf40a39a-0721-4fd4-84f3-adc28aee1158" from the xml, if i select name (as in your answer), the name appears, but removing that, nothing appears from xml - which i need the text between the characterString tag

Comment: @MapMan OK, I only had the "name" column in my test. I have removed it from the query. But the result of the query should be what you want: `cf40a39a-0721-4fd4-84f3-adc28aee1158`

Comment: i missed out a tag on the example xml (</gmd:GEMINI_Metadata>) which i have added, however before the PASSING keyword, i have replaced '\metadata' with '"\ gmd:GEMINI_Metadata" but nothing appears

Comment: @MapMan You just need to adjust the path. `PATH 'gmd:GEMINI_Metadata/gmd:fileIdentifier/gco:CharacterString'`